# C# Entity Framework and DB - change from smallint to int

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Due to a certain change we have to make, some columns in the db have to be changed from **smallint** to **int** and as a result, we have to change the code variables from **short** to **int**.

Since it is a pretty big change, we would like to do it in 2 steps - first change the db and only then change the code (or the other way around).

We did a small test - changed a column in a specific table from **smallint** to **int** without changing the code - the code variable is still expecting **short**.

When using EF to get results from the DB and assigning it to the appropriate c# class, we get the following error (which is reasonable):

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The 'CountryID' property on 'TestClass' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int16'

EDIT: similar exception raises if we first try to change the code variable to be **int** and working with db column as **smallint**:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: The 'CountryID' property on 'TestClass' could not be set to a 'System.Int16' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'

Some code and data:

- The DB table has a column named `CountryID (int, not null)`.
- the matching class is:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public short CountryID { get; set; }
}
```

the modelBuilder is:

```
    ToTable("Country");
    // mapping an int column in the db (CountryID) to a short variable in the code (CountryID)
    Property(t => t.CountryID).HasColumnName("CountryID").IsRequired();
```

Trying to query the table with EF:

`var listOfCountryIDs = dbContext.TestEntity.Where(t => t.CountryID == countryID)`, raises the exception.

We tried to force the model builder with adding `.HasColumnType("smallint")` but it didn't help.
Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107080/entity-framework-code-first-cast-smallint-and-integer-to-int32).

Of course it works if we change both the code and the db to work with ints (or short & smallint).

Is there any way to apply this change in 2 steps? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid,you need to change datatype both at DB and Model level simultaneously. Reason is why you getting the exception mentioned in the questions is, entityframework trying to put 4 byte data from DB into 2 byte of Model, since no direct casting of this type is available hence you facing it.

As you mentioned that this is very large change, I suggest you to go one DB/One model at a time.

thanks